# Is there a predefined callback function for custom categories?

Tags: metabox

I am trying to create a meta box *(with the same feature as the category meta box, the one that searches categories)* , except I want to make one that searches a custom category.
I'm hoping that I can rely on a predefined callback function that will work with custom categories.

I tried the method from [this article](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-change-the-titles-of-your-wordpress-category-and-tag-meta-boxes/?utm_expid=3606929-85.mSQ3nlVLSHShaT4smJ6ikw.0&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F) but to no avail:

```
add_meta_box(
    'metaboxID',
    "Meta box Title",
    'myCustomPostType_myCustomCategory_meta_box',
    'myCustomPostType',
    'side',
    'high'
);
```

When using `add_meta_box`, is there a predefined callback function for custom categories, such as `post_categories_meta_box`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The callback you're looking for is `post_categories_meta_box` which we can use via a custom callback.

```
// Add your custom meta box.
function your_custom_meta_box() {
  add_meta_box( 'your-custom-meta-box', 'Custom Meta Box', 'my_taxonomy_meta_box_cb', 'post', 'side', 'high', null );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'your_custom_meta_box' );

// Our custom callback.
function my_taxonomy_meta_box_cb( $post, $box ) {

  // Pass in the taxonomy we'd like to use.
  $box[ 'args' ][ 'taxonomy' ] = 'listing_category';

  post_categories_meta_box( $post, $box );
}
```

Thanks to @birgire for pointing out how not to duplicate code. :-)

Comment: Not sure I understand what OP is looking for, but instead of suggesting code duplication, you could just call `post_categories_meta_box( $post, $box )` within the custom `my_taxonomy_meta_box_cb()` wrapper, together with the correct taxonomy:   `$box['taxonomy'] = 'listing_category';`

Comment: Nicely done, @birgire. Answer updated to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: nice, but note that `post_categories_meta_box()` returns nothing and input arguments must match (fixed that)

Comment: ps: I see you removed the $post, $box input arguments, but I think we should keep them ;-) otherwise they're undefined.

Comment: sorry, thought you removed them. I put them back. :-)