# Find callback function for custom taxonomy metabox

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, custom-taxonomy, metabox, tags

I'm looking for a way to move my custom taxonomy metabox (on the right side) to the post area (the middle). I'm aware you can simply drag and drop it, but I want it in the post area by default for new users.

My approach was to remove it using `remove_meta_box()`, and then add it back using `add_meta_box()`. The problem is that **I don't know what callback function to call when adding it back.**

```
/* Remove movies metabox from sidepanel */
function hide_metabox(){
    remove_meta_box( 'tagsdiv-movies', 'movies' , 'side' );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'hide_metabox' );


/* Add back movies metabox, but in post area */
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_back_post');
    function add_back_post(){
    /* Not sure what to put as the thrid argument */
    add_meta_box('tagsdiv-movies','Movies', 'WHAT_CALLBACK_ARG', 'movies', 'normal', 'high');
}
```

[image: Custom metabox "movies"]

As a side note, I created the taxonomy using [Custom Post Type UI](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) (CPT UI) which basically follows the standard procedure when creating a custom taxonomy.

I'm not sure either if this answers my question as I don't quite follow the information provided here:
[Is there a predefined callback function for custom categories?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/240409/is-there-a-predefined-callback-function-for-custom-categories).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The callback you need for non-hierarchical taxonomies is `post_tags_meta_box`.

The callback you need for hierarchical taxonomies is `post_categories_meta_box`.

For your example, the code would be:

```
/* Remove movies metabox from sidepanel */
function hide_metabox(){
    remove_meta_box(
        'tagsdiv-movies',
        'your-post-type' ,
        'side'
    );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'hide_metabox' );


/* Add back movies metabox, but in post area */
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_back_post');
    function add_back_post(){
    add_meta_box(
        'tagsdiv-movies',
        'Movies',
        'post_tags_meta_box',
        'your-post-type',
        'normal',
        'high',
        array( 'taxonomy' => 'movies' )
    );
}
```

One other important variable is the metabox ID. In your example, `tagsdiv-movies` targets a metabox for a non-hierarchical taxonomy with slug `movies`. If that same taxonomy was hierarchical, the ID would be `moviesdiv`.

Comment: You are godsent! I tried `post_tags_meta_box` before, but I was missing the array argument! This solved my 2 days of headache, thank you!

Comment: Indeed the array with the taxonomy seemed to fix for me too.